# Python sub-setting output of NumPy Array is a bit confusing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

a 2-dimension numpy array

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([[1,   2,  3,  4,  5], 
             [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

## select row 0 to end and column 0 (output is 1D)

```
In [1]: z[0:,0]
Out[1]: array([ 1, 11])
```

## select row 0 to end and column 0 (output is 2D)

```
In [2]: z[0:,:1]
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1],
       [11]])
```

The sub-setting criteria is similar; however, why is the output format different (1D-Array vs 2D-Array)?

Comment: When using the colon `:` in indexing you will get a range of values (even if you just request one value). In other words, the colon means that it will maintain the dimensionality of the axis. Without it you will just get the projection at the requested index.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. Understood. If I have one colon in index, it returns 1D array. If I have 2 colon in index, it returns 2D array.

Comment: The colon `:` creates a `slice` (a well define Python class).  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html describes basic indexing with slices.  And notes that indexing with an integer is like `i:I+1` slice, but it reduces the dimension.  You may need to reread that indexing page several times, and play with a number of examples before getting a good feel for this.  Some familiarity with list and string indexing helps, since arrays generalize those ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the difference is in the way of selection. When a range is selected dimension on that axis is added, however when an axis is set at a constant a subdimensional array is selected.
This is same for any other array, see python lists for example

```
>>> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> arr[0]
'a'
>>> arr[:1]
['a']
>>>
```

[Check Other indexing options Numpy doc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/doc/indexing.py#L74)